# Type 'Type' is not generic

Tags: angular, pagination, ng2-bootstrap

I am trying to introduce pagination to my app but getting the error. I am following [ng2-bootstrap](http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/pagination)

this is how I declared fields in my component:

```
 public bigTotalItems: number = IEmployee.length;
 public maxSize: number = 5;
```

And this is how I used them in template:

```
<pagination [totalItems]="bigTotalItems" [maxSize]="maxSize" class="pagination-sm"
                        [boundaryLinks]="true"></pagination>
```

Heres my app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { PaginationModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
    imports: [PaginationModule.forRoot(),BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule ],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]

})
export class AppModule { }
```

I am getting this error in `component-loader.class.d.ts` file.

Also attaching package.json to share the dependency versions I am using:

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "docker-build": "docker build -t ng2-quickstart .",
    "docker": "npm run docker-build && docker run -it --rm -p 3000:3000 -p 3001:3001 ng2-quickstart",
    "pree2e": "npm run webdriver:update",
    "e2e": "tsc && concurrently \"http-server -s\" \"protractor protractor.config.js\" --kill-others --success first",
    "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "test-once": "tsc && karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings",
    "webdriver:update": "webdriver-manager update"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "0.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.15",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.3.3",
    "ng2-paginate": "^0.1.0",
    "ng2-pagination": "^2.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.0.4",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "tslint": "^3.7.4",
    "lodash": "^4.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.3",
    "karma-cli": "^0.1.2",
    "karma-htmlfile-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
    "protractor": "^3.3.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

Is there something that someone can help with. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should update your angular version. Since [2.0.0-rc.6](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-rc6-2016-08-31) the `Type` class is now generic (which means `Type<T>`). Ng2-bootstrap obviously updated their code to comply with this change.

I can also suggest you to go back a few versions with `ng2-bootstrap`, but why dwell in the past. You should just update to the latest angular. RC-5 was released almost half a year ago, and migrating to a release version instead of staying in a release candidate state will help with more than just this issue.

Comment: So should I just update the packages mentioned as `rc5` in package.json to `rc6` and leave other dependecies as is?

Comment: Well, to resolve your issue. Yes, that will work. But why would you want to stay in a release candidate version?

Comment: If not `rc` which stable version should I migrate my dependencies to?

Comment: Start good, and begin with [angular4.0.0-rc.2](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md), I know it's not stable, but they will be soon. This way you are all the way up to date. Just remember to check for an update every week (they update every week)

Answer (score 1):

My issue was a wrong import, so make sure you're importing the correct `Type` from `@angular/core`:

`import { Type } from '@angular/core';`